position controller not working as expected
I'm trying to make a rover with flippers which the robot can rotate to help it climb over obstacles. I'm using a position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController. While the flipper does go to a position, this is immediate and not gradual. This also shoots the robot in the air.
When echoing /joint_states, the velocities and effort does not change.
I have tried adding a PID controller into the config file but this does not seem to do anything. Does anyone have any suggestions?
I am now in the middle of making my own position controller with a PID controller

I assume that you are simulating your rover in gazebo classic and have position command interfaces?
JointGroupPositionController doesn't have any feedback loop (aka PID controller), but only sets the command interface to the value you send.
There exists a PID controller already, and we backported this to humble.
When you use the position interface in gazebo classic, then there is no physics engine involved but you just override the joints' positions -> no effort is calculated. A bit related to this issue. You can try to use the position_pid configuration of gazebo_ros2_control.

Thank you. I'm using ROS2 Humble with Gazebo Classic i'm not sure if PID Controller works with Humble. The lack of a feedback i'm guessing is why when subscribed to /joint_states, i'm seeing effort:NaN?
Have you any suggestion on how to proceed with this? Whenever i use a ros2_control controller, the robot's joints act erratically. My aim is for me to input a position which the robot's flippers will then go to. I was thinking adding a PID controller would help make this a smooth transition

I updated the answer
